# Is there a way to protect oneself from Mercurial identity theft?

Tags: security, mercurial

Is there a way to protect oneself from Mercurial identity theft?

The case is if someone deliberately commit bugs into the code using another developer's name with the goal of getting that person fired or mis-credited.

Is there a way to stop that from happening or is it a non issue?

Comment: Maybe an interesting read (no solution in it though): http://greenspringdesign.com/blog/?p=11

Comment: What if I'm working on a change with another dev and we're sharing bundles back and forth (to not pollute the main repo). At the end, I might push commits with his name on them, but it would be perfectly legit.

Comment: @robert, exaclty this is the point of the DVCS - anyone can push changesets which may include changes done by other persons. Therefore you somehow need to verify whether you trust the commits which are to be pushed, and this can be achieved by using cryptographic signing on the commit (which is similar to signing e-mails or any data in order to confirm the identity). The server can then check the commit signatures against a list of trusted entities (certificates, certification authority etc.) to ensure that only trusted commits are performed. Each signature can be matched to a distinct owner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know a way to actually restrict the commits not so include a "stolen" identity, but if you have a centralized repository you should be able to securely audit who has pushed which changes to the server, and thereby track down the identity thief.

---

**Edit:** there seems to be support for signing commits with two extensions, the [CommitsigsExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommitsigsExtension) as well as the seemingly less secure approach implemented by the [GpgExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GpgExtension).

Signing the changesets effectively prevents identity theft since the thief does not have the private key of the identity he wants to steal, thereby he cannot sign the commit.

Comment: I like the content you have before your edit. For example, SourceForge will show in the "develop" section of a project who pushed what. It could be tracked without too much difficulty with a push hook, I think. Just no one's done it as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

The Mozilla project does this in the form of a pushlog.  They made a trivial change to the web templates to show the output of a pushlog which is easily created at push time using a `changeset` hook.  Here's what their log looks like:

http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/pushloghtml

A hook that creates such a log could be as easy as:

```
[hooks]
changeset = echo $REMOTE_USER pushed HG_NODE >> /path/to/my/pushlog
```

In practice this is one of those things that everything thinks will be a problem when they first hear that the "user" field is entirely falsifiable, but in practice is just never actually a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use access control on the "main" repo and log requests. If you log who authenticated to push each commit, you can tell who really pushed a particular commit, regardless if the info in the repository.

Comment: while I do understand what ACLs do and how they protect invalid commits on the centralized repo, I don't see how the extension can prevent identity theft on a local repository? Maybe you could give some details on that?

Comment: In order to modify my local Mercurial repository, you need to be able to log in as me. If you're worried about security, every repo that is accessible to more than one person needs this access control/logging. Individual developer repos do not. Yes, I could have a misleading local commit that appears to be by someone else, but you could catch it when it's pushed.

Comment: Assume this: I have a clone of the repo and I can push changes as myself. Now I locally commit a change using your name and then push this using my account - this will push the commited changes with your name attached to the commit! This question is **not** about access control, but about ensuring that someone doesn't abuse someone else's identity when committing changes.